Test Fails after Establishing Connection to Database
I have a repo for a node app that uses an object to store the data temporarily. I updated the code to connect to MongoDB and some of the tests start failing.
The test is one with supertest.
The code that connects with MongoDB in my repo is named withMongo while the master branch contains the code when it uses an object as a temporary database.
The repository link is https://github.com/uzoma-nwanne/node_express_starter.git
Any help to get the withMongo branch to run correctly would be appreciated
I ran the code using a temporary database object and it worked and the tests ran successfully.
When I added a connection to a real database, it also worked but the tests started failing.
I expect the tests to be successful after connecting to a database.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
